# Jquery validation: dynamic inline validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have the following html code:

```
<form>
    <table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
               <span>Quantity<span class="pull-right">3</span>
               <input type="hidden" class="" value="3" name="quantity[]">
           </td>
           <td class="form-inline">
                <label>Cantidad Warehouse</label>
                <input id="qty_warehouse_1" type="text" name="cantidad_despacho[]" class="required input-mini">
           </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
               <span>Quantity<span class="pull-right">5</span>
               <input type="hidden" class="" value="5" name="quantity[]">
           </td>
           <td class="form-inline">
                <label>Cantidad Warehouse</label>
                <input id="qty_warehouse_2" type="text" name="cantidad_despacho[]" class="required input-mini">
           </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
            <button id="submit" value="send" name="button">Send</button>
</form>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Where each row is dynamically generated. I need to perform a validation for each input with the name **Qty_warehouse so its max value won't be greater than the hidden value at the same row**. This is what i've been trying to do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form").validate();
    $("[id*='qty_warehouse']").rules("add", {
        required: true,
        max: function() {
        return $(this).parents("tr").eq(0).find("input[name='quantity[]']").val();
        },
        min: 0,
        messages: {
            required: "Introduzca la cantidad disponible en despacho"
        }
    });

    $("#submit").click(function() {
        alert($("form").valid());
    });
});​
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. this is the fiddle link if you'd like to make some tests. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wHdKt/)

Comment: it was just a sample code. The original code is a table with a lot of data, not for layout issues, and all the labels points to their respetive input tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within your `max` function `this` is not what you think it is, it is the `window`. To verify, simply call `console.log(this)` inside the function and inspect in browser console.

Add an argument for element to the max function and use that to start the traverse. Also convert the input value to a number.

```
  max: function(element) {
        var max=   $(element).parents("tr").eq(0).find("input[name='quantity[]']").val();    
        return 1*max;
    }
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/wHdKt/1/

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know you can pass arguments to that function.

Comment: to be honest, I didn't know you could either so I assumed you could. I passed several arguments, logged them to console to see if they were defined and what they might be and came up with solution that way